# Swift on macOS: quit other apps

Tags: swift, nsworkspace

I want to create a utility app for myself for macOS. It shall quit other apps. The following code does not produce errors but it also does not quit the System-Preferences-App:

```
func quitSettings() {
    let appToTerminate = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications.first(
        where: {$0.bundleIdentifier == "com.apple.systempreferences" }
    )
    if let appToTerminate  {
        appToTerminate.terminate()
    }
}
```

Update:

When I run this function in a simple playground it actually works! However, running it in from a SwiftUi App does still not work:

```
import SwiftUI
import Cocoa

@main
struct QuitApp: App {

init() {
    quitSettings()
}

func quitSettings() {
    let appToTerminate = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications.first(
        where: {$0.bundleIdentifier == "com.apple.systempreferences" }
    )
    if let appToTerminate  {
        print(appToTerminate.terminate()) // prints false
    }
}

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

}

Does anyone know how that can happen and how to fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It closes System Settings.app. Are you certain `appToTerminate` is returning a value? Does your call to `.terminate()` return false? (I assume that your app is not sandboxed, since sandboxed apps can't terminate anything.) How are you checking that System Settings isn't being quit? (Visually? In code? If in code, remember that `.terminate()` returns before the receiver exits.) Is a modal dialog up? (In that case Settings won't quit, even with Cmd-Q.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It returns false. I check if it works visually. I updated my question as I found out that it works from a playground but not from a SwiftUi App.

Comment: My SwiftUI is sandboxed my Playground is not so this must be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note in the comments, your app is sandboxed. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsrunningapplication/1528922-terminate#):

> Sandboxed applications can’t use this method to terminate other applications. This method returns false when called from a sandboxed application.

If you want to be able to terminate other apps, you'll need to remove sandboxing.